# Trouble about input having the same name

Tags: php, html, post

is there a way that i can differentiate the value with the same name?

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="name1">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="name2">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="name3">
```

is there a way that when i post an id, the value that will be posted would be name2?

Comment: Why you giving same name to multiple elements ?

Comment: change the name to `id[]` so that they'll be treated as arrays.

Comment: What is your purpose? To pass some parameters from page to page? How can you differ them? Considered saving to db/cookies/session?

Comment: I suspect that what you really need is a `radio` group or a `select`

Comment: yeah but when i changed the name to an array, the posted value would be "array" my purpose is that when i use post, the value that will be posted would be "name2".

Answer (score 2):

Use array for the name

```
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="name1">
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="name2">
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="name3">
```

which provides all the values in array.

hope this help.

Comment: i tried setting the name as an array, but when i echo $_POST['id'];

the value that will be posted is array.

Comment: @user2102316 exactly, so it would be accessed with `$_POST['id'][0]` for the first one and increment `[0]` for each additional one... or use a `foreach` loop or something similar.

Comment: You need to loop through the array and do something with the values. Try something like `foreach($_POST['id'] as $id) { doStuff(); }`

Answer (score 0):

use different names for different variables.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id2" value="name2">
```

Comment: im actually using a while loop to create the inputs, so all of the name are the same but different value. so is there anyway that i can differentiate the value of it that has the same name?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not do that. You need to specify different names
or to use somthing like an array. 
This can be done by setting the name id[].

What want you to do?

You can set the value of the hidden field dynamicaly with javascript, if that is what you are looking for.